# How to get a full path of file uploaded via HTML form in django view.py file?

Tags: python, django, path

home.html

```html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name = 'img' >
        <button type="submit"> Post On Facebook </button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          # get the image absolute location 
        
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

I want the file path, so that I can upload the file on facebook using GraphAPI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544523/how-do-i-get-a-files-absolute-path-after-being-uploaded-in-django/42545154

Comment: you should find this in any tutorial or in official documentation. So better find some tutorial and you will get solutions much faster than asking on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your upload path in your models file.
Then you can save it to that particular path in your view function.

For details refer - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html